# Why conditions can not be added to the outer loop

Tags: java, loops

Here is my demo, it's very simple, but I can't add addition to the outer loop  `i<10`  if I try to add, it reminded  me:

> This method must return a result of type String

```
public String testFor() {
    for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
             return "success";
        }
    }
}
```

why does this happen?

Comment: you have to return something in the end before you close your method!

Comment: What's your expectation?

Comment: What IDE / compiler are you using? PS don't upvote comment 3, he IS returning something

Comment: I think you are hitting the limits of what the compiler can (is allowed to) infer about your blocks terminating with a return or not. The rules are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) but I can't yet figure out which bit refers to your case specifically.

Comment: @Jorge.V  eclipse IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant sections of JLS are [Sec 8.4.7 Method body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7); the relevant part of this is:

> If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

(["complete normally"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1) is slightly confusing terminology; it basically means to complete without executing a `return`, `throw` or `System.exit` statement)

and [Sec 14.21, Unreachable statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21). The relevant part of this is:

> A non-empty block that is not a switch block can complete normally iff the last statement in it can complete normally.
>
> ...
>
> A basic for statement can complete normally iff at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The for statement is reachable, there is a condition expression, and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
> - There is a reachable break statement that exits the for statement.
>
> The contained statement is reachable iff the for statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is false.

The inner loop isn't actually relevant to the behavior: you will see exactly the same behavior with:

```
public String testFor() {
  // Compiler error if you uncomment the condition.
  for(int i = 0; /* i<10 */; i++) { 
  }
}
```

Without the condition, neither of the bulleted conditions are true, so the loop cannot complete normally; as such, it cannot reach after the loop. As such, no `return` (or `throw` or `System.exit`) statement is required.

If you add the condition `i<10`, that's not a compile-time constant, so the loop can complete normally. As such, you would need to add a a `return` (or `throw` or `System.exit`) statement after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The inner loop and the `return` statement are of little importance here.

The following snippet will compile, without the presence of a `return` statement:

```
public String testFor() {
    for (int i = 0; ;i++) {
    }
}
```

The behavior is specified in the Java Language Specification ([JLS §8.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)):

> If a method is declared to have a return type
>   ([§8.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)),
>   then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can
>   complete normally
>   ([§14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-14.1)).

In this case, the body of the method cannot complete normally because of the infinite loop, therefore a return statement (or other abnormal termination, e.g. `throw SomeException()`) is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with:

```
for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
}
```

this is actually similar to

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    ...
    i++
}
```

And so the compiler knows, it is an infinite loop.

However,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
}
// what to return here?
```

The compiler needs to return a string when this loop finishes.  <strike>It doesn't really go into the inside of the second `for`, to know it will return the first time it enters it.</strike> and it doesn't evaluate the second loop, as hinted by Jaroslaw Pawlak

Comment: It's not about the second loop. `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { return "success"; }` will not compile either. The reason is that the loop condition is not checked at compile time.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Understood. But why it's not an error if we are removing the condition. If condition is not checked at compile time, how does it matter whether to put the condition or not.

Comment: The rule for non-void methods is that every code path that returns, must return a value. In the case of an infinite loop, there's no return path, so there's no need to return a value. You can remove the inner loop and the return statement altogether, and it will still compile as long as there's an infinite loop.

Comment: you should add this as an answer. It should be accepted.

Comment: @Abhishek as mentioned in other answers, if you remove condition, it changes into an infinite loop, and this is something that compiler does check. See Robby Cornelissen's answer

Answer (score 0):

Because if you add a condition to outer loop you should return at least one string type return guarantee to the caller so your code should like this:

```
public String testFor() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
              return "success";
          }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: The code just looked differently when I answered ...

```
public String testFor()
{
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }
}
```

This code works aswell. "j++" is dead code, because we only enter the inner loop once before we return with "success".